# keeping parentheses size the same in Input cells when using 2D math

Tags: front-end

I like to group the 2 parts of the `If` statement and others like it by using `()` to help me be able to still understand what my code is doing the next day I look at it.

I started to use 2D math in input cells, and it is a nice feature of Mathematica.

But noticed that `()` changes size depending on what is inside them. So I end up with non-symmetrical (different size) parentheses within the same logical grouping. An example will help show this:

[image]

Notice how the top `()` are small compared to the lower `()`. The code will look better on the screen if the sizes of these `()` are kept the same. (either both large, or both small, is not important, as long as the size is the same)

This happens with `With` and any other such command.

I know the `()` are not needed. I just use them to make the code easy to read. When I have complicated logic, these help me see the parts more clearly.

Here is the actual code that generated the above converted to `InputForm` in order to paste it here

```
Clear["Global`*"]
If[x == 1, x = 0, x = Sqrt[y^2] ];
```

Question is: Is there a way to control this aspect of the display in input cells for 2D math so that parentheses are the same even if using 2D math?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the height of the `()` in `StandardForm` input cells to be fixed to one character tall, modify the `"StandardForm"` style in corresponding stylesheet would help:

```
Cell[StyleData["StandardForm"], SpanMaxSize->0]
```

Note this will affect all spanning characters such as  parentheses, brackets, braces and etc. Please do search *span* in document center for more relevant options and details.